# GridView does not load schema from the SQL stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, gridview, schema

I have gridview, when I connect the sqldatasource and run the application, data from stored procedure is shown but when i switch to design mode, the schema does not loads in gridview. I need that schema to rearrange columns and for formatting purpose.

I never had this problem before, All of sudden it is a problem.

**What I tried so far** "Refresh Schema" brings up the dialog which list all the parameters I am passing to the storedprocedure. After I changed DBType for every single parameter, it still give me an error, says "check your connection and storedprocedure". While the storedprodure does run, shouldn't it automatically update the schema in gridview. I still have the default 3 columns of gridview.

Note: I may get around the problem by adding each column manually but I am doing this to fix problem in the page, in the first place, dont want to run again in gridview problem. This is a new page that I am building. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, Schema is not updated just from StoredProcedure because simple there is not enough information how many columns will be returned.

To work around this issue and sort of quick fix, do the following.

Copy the query from you stored procedure and change the SQLDatasource from stored procedure to Select statement. Run your select statement and finish. Notice that your schema will now be updated.

You can now set your SQLDataSource back to stored procedure and the schema will remain the same.

---

It also occured to me that when you run a stored procedure, the column names are updated in the query using the name 'Databound col0' 'Databound Col1' and so on

I am not sure sometime it does, sometime it does not. Right click on Gridview and click Referesh Schema does not work as it gives some error.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @hmd, when there is not enough info, especially if there is another perceived dataset being return, i.e you are doing something that returns blank or debug data (rows affected, etc.).  A workaround for this is to put "SET NOCOUNT OFF" in the beginning of your procedure and then set it back "ON" again before you return the data.  This is also a problem on SSRS.